# How can I split the String output of an ls command into an array on just the filenames in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop

I am running a hdfs dfs -ls command and storing the output in a variable in bash. The output stored in the variable looks like this:

```
Found 3 items drwxrwx--- - user user 0 2017-07-31 15:47 /user/example/test/dt=2017-02-22 drwxr-xr-x - user user 0 2017-09-11 11:32 /user/example/test/dt=2017-09-06 drwxrwxr-x - user user 0 2017-09-08 15:46 /user/example/test/dt=2017-09-07
```

I am trying to parse the directory names only into an array, which would look something like:

```
array=[dt=2017-02-22, dt=2017-09-06, dt=2017-09-07]
```

Due to the limitations of adding extra switches on the original -ls command (due to the Hadoop API), I have struggled to get the output in any other format to that shown in the first code snippet.

Any suggestions are appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it outputs to one line

Comment: Are you sure that's not just because you're using e.g. `echo $var` instead of `echo "$var"`, so all your whitespace is being collapsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  array=(`dfs -ls | grep -Eo "df=[^ ]+"`)

  echo ${array[0]}
```

Comment: This gave no output unfortunately. The implemented code I tried looked like this: files=($(hadoop fs -ls /user/example/test | grep -Eo "df=[^ ]+"))

Comment: Now your output in ${files[@]}

Comment: Just noticed the typo in your grep and fixed it, now this solution works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I changed "df=[^ ]+" to dt=[^ ]+"

Comment: Very strange, quotes must be symmetric. I think, you have other quote somewhere.

Comment: Aha no, that was just my poor typing, apologies. The working grep is this: grep -Eo "dt=[^ ]+", and the one you suggested was matching 'df' instead of 'dt', which is why it returned zero results. Thanks again though, it's working a treat

Answer (score 0):

With ***grep*** tool:

```
arr=($(dfs -ls | grep -o 'dt=[^[:space:]]*'))
```

---

All `arr` items:

```
echo ${arr[@]}
dt=2017-02-22 dt=2017-09-06 dt=2017-09-07
```